# Adding '.' using jQuery

Tags: javascript, ascii

The javascript length and subString function does not take into account non ascii characters.

I have a function that substrings the users input to 400 characters if they enter more than 400 characters.

e.g

```
function reduceInput (data) {

 if (data.length > 400)
 {
 var reducedSize = data.substring(0,400);
 }
return reducedSize;
}
```

However, if non ascii chars is entered (double byte chars) then this does not work. It does not take into account the character types in the equation.

I have another function that loops round each charaters, and if it is a non ascii, it increments a counter and then works out what the true count is. It works but it is a bit of a hack.

Is there a more efficient approach to doing this or is there no other alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The native character set of JavaScript and web browsers in general is UTF-16. Strings are sequences of UTF-16 code units. There is no concept of "double byte" character encodings.

If you want to calculate how many bytes a String will take up in a particular double-byte encoding, you will need to know what encoding it is and how to encode it yourself; that information will not be accessible to JavaScript natively. So for example with Shift_JIS you will have to know which characters are kana that can be encoded to a single byte, and which take part in double-byte kanji sequences.

There is not any encoding that stores all code units that represent ASCII in one byte and all code units other than ASCII in two bytes, so whatever question you are trying to solve by counting non-ASCII as two, the loop-and-add probably isn't the right answer.

In any case, the old-school double-byte encodings are a horrible anachronism to be avoided wherever possible. If you want a space-efficient byte encoding, you want UTF-8. It's easy to calculate the length of a string in UTF-8 bytes because JS has a sneaky built-in UTF-8 encoder you can leverage:

```
var byten= unescape(encodeURIComponent(chars)).length;
```

Snipping a string to 400 bytes is somewhat trickier because you want to avoid breaking a multi-byte sequence. You'll get an exception if you try to UTF-8-decode something with a broken sequence at the end, so catch it and try again:

```
var bytes= unescape(encodeURIComponent(chars)).slice(0, 400);
while (bytes.length>0) {
    try {
        chars= decodeURIComponent(escape(bytes));
        break
    } catch (e) {
        bytes= bytes.slice(0, -1);
    }
}
```

But it's unusual to want to limit input based on number of bytes it will take up in a particular encoding. Straight limit on number of characters is far more typical. What're you trying to do?

Comment: Very good answer. I was about to write up something similar. The only thing I was going to add was that UTF-8 encoding shows up when you are interfacing with an outside entity such as an input field, or my mozrepl connection from emacs, a server that sends utf-8 data, or maybe even the javascript source code itself that is encoded using UTF-8. When this happens, you decode the strings to native UTF-16 strings, operate on them, and reencode back to UTF-8 before you interface with that outside entity again.

Answer (score 1):

A regex can do the job i think

```
var data = /.{0,400}/.exec(originalData)[0];
```

Comment: because: If you want to retrieve the part of the string that was matched, call the exec() function of the RegExp object that you created, e.g.: mymatch = myregexp.exec("subject"). This function returns an array. The zeroth item in the array will hold the text that was matched by the regular expression.